# Nested IEnumerable collections within Class filtering on multiple conditions

Tags: c#, linq, dapper

I may not being using the correct term "nested", but you can see the 2 classes I have below. `IEnumerable<OperationTask>` is in the `IEnumerable<AxApp>`.

I hope I can explain this correctly:

1. I have a method that is reading values from a txt file into a string[]

   ```
   string[] appNames = _appNamesRepository.GetAppNameListFromInputFile(fileName);
   ```
2. Then I create an `IEnumerable<AxApp>` collection with a method that reads a SQL table and returns the AxApp properties for each app value in the txt file.

   ```
   IEnumerable<AxApp> allAxApps = _axAppRepository.GetAllAxAppsInList(appNames);
   ```
3. I need to filter the `IEnumerable<AxApp>` collection based on specific criteria from values in the `IEnumerable<OperationTask>`.  I can get a basic lambda search to work, but I can't return the correct result if I have more than a couple values I'm basing this on.

For example the below will only return an `IEnumerable<AxApp>` if the appid, operationType, and operationStatus.Incomplete are NOT in `IEnumerable<OperationTasks>`.

```
var test = allAxApps.Where(app => 
              !app.operationTasks
                     .Any(task => task.appId == app.appid && 
                                  task.operationType == operationType &&
                                  task.operationStatus != Status.Incomplete));
```

*HOWEVER, I need to go a step further, if the operationType == "Differential", I can only return the AxApp IF IN `IEnmerable<OperationTask>` there is a collection where type = "NewConversion", status = "Complete", but NO type = "Finish", but can include types = "Differential"*

```
public class AxApp
{
    public AxApp()
    {

    }
    public AxApp(int id, string appname, string dlname)
    {
        this.appname = appname;
        appid = id;
        this.dlname = dlname;
    }
    public string appname { get; set; }
    public int appid { get; set; }
    public string dlname { get; set; }
    public string dtname { get; set; }
    public int flags { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AxDlsd> dlsdRecords { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AxDl> dlRecords { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OperationTask> operationTasks { get; set; }
    public DateTime startMerge { get; set; }
    public DateTime endMerge { get; set; }
}


public class OperationTask
{
    public int operationId { get; set; }
    public int appId { get; set; }
    public OperationType operationType { get; set; }
    public Status operationStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime startTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime endTime { get; set; }
}
```

**Method that returns the AppData from any value in the string[]**

```
public IEnumerable<AxApp> GetAllAxAppsInList(string[] appNamesInput)
{
    string query = @"SELECT appid, appname, dlname, dtname, flags FROM dbo.ae_apps WHERE appname = @_appname";
    string opQuery = @"SELECT operationId, appId, operationType, operationStatus, startTime, endTime FROM dbo.RDS_ConversionOperationsHistory WHERE appid = @_appId";

    using (var connection = _dbConnectionFactory.GetAxDbConnection())
    {
        foreach (string appname in appNamesInput)
        {
            AxApp result = connection.QuerySingle<AxApp>(query, new { _appname = appname });
            result.operationTasks = connection.Query<OperationTask>(opQuery, new { _appId = result.appid });
            yield return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**IEnumerable for AxApp/OperationTask**

[0] = {RDS.Conversion.UtilityLibrary.Models.AxApp}

```
    [0] {RDS.Conversion.UtilityLibrary.Models.AxApp}    RDS.Conversion.UtilityLibrary.Models.AxApp
    appid   1   int
    appname "PLIC_CENT_1"   string
    dlRecords   null    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<RDS.Conversion.UtilityLibrary.Models.AxDl
    dlname  "ae_dlsd1_SIM"  string
    dlsdRecords null    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<RDS.Conversion.UtilityLibrary.Models.AxDlsd>
    dtname  "ae_dt1"    string
    endMerge    {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}  System.DateTime
    flags   16384   int
    operationTasks  Count = 3   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<RDS.Conversion.UtilityLibrary.Models.OperationTask> {System.Collections.Generic.List<RDS.Conversion.UtilityLibrary.Models.OperationTask>}
    startMerge  {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}  System.DateTime


    operationTasks  Count = 3   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<RDS.Conversion.UtilityLibrary.Models.OperationTask> {System.Collections.Generic.List<RDS.Conversion.UtilityLibrary.Models.OperationTask>}





    [0] {RDS.Conversion.UtilityLibrary.Models.OperationTask}    RDS.Conversion.UtilityLibrary.Models.OperationTask
    appId   1   int
    endTime {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}  System.DateTime
    operationId 18  int
    operationStatus Complete    RDS.Conversion.UtilityLibrary.Models.Status
    operationType   NewConversion   RDS.Conversion.UtilityLibrary.Models.OperationType
    startTime   {9/28/2018 12:53:51 PM} System.DateTime
```

Comment: Can you post some input and expected output? So that's easier to understand what you are looking for

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Does this help?  Just edited the post ..  My output that i'm expecting is the same AxApp collection but filtered based on the OperationTask criteria.

Comment: Doesn't really help. I meant more like given a set of AxApp/OperationTask what output the query should give you

Comment: This question is written very complex.  It desires a conversation to understand what you're wanting to achieve, in which case, may end up in a lot of comments and confusion.  Could you shorten the question more directly to the point? I get the jist of it but it feels like too many moving parts to completely understand your problem.  Then again it may just be me and if so apologies.

Comment: My application is passing operationType, which could be "NewConversion", "Differential", or "Final".  each operation (process) that is run creates an entry in the OperationTask table which is what the OperationTask class is used for.  Basically, prior to running one of these tasks, I have to check the OperationTask collections for each appid to see if they have been run before.  Example would be, operationTask = "Differential".  I can't run an app through the process if there is NO "New Conversion" or there is, but it's "Incomplete".  I wish I could make my question more direct, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but, it may get you in the right direction.

```
        test = allAxApps.Where(app =>
        {
            var tasks = app.operationTasks.ToList();
            var differentialCondition = false;

            if (operationType == OperationType.Differential)
            {
                var hasCompletedNewConversion = tasks.Any(task =>
                    task.operationType == OperationType.NewConversion &&
                    task.operationStatus == Status.Complete);

                var hasFinish = tasks.Any(task => task.operationType == OperationType.Finish);

                differentialCondition = hasCompletedNewConversion && !hasFinish;
            }

            var hasIncomplete = tasks.Any(task =>
                task.appId == app.appid &&
                task.operationType == operationType &&
                task.operationStatus == Status.Incomplete);

            return differentialCondition && !hasIncomplete;
        });
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head with this one!! Thank you so much!